# Choosing Parameter In Excel

Tags: excel, excel-2007

I have a datasource that populates my sheet from sql server. There is a parameter to refresh the data. Can I have the choices come from a drop down menu on another sheet?

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can do that. How do you acquire the parameter now?

You can have your code read the linked to cell of the dropdown and use that in your code.

Although you asked about getting the parameter from from another sheet, you could also do this with a form and a dropdown within it.

Answer (score 0):

You can do it without programming. Just link the dropbox to the cell which contains your parameter.